# How can I convert the AAC audio in an MP4 from CBR to VBR?

Tags: video, audio, conversion

I'm trying to get MP4 video files I have created in **Corel VideoStudio** to play on an **XBox 360** via streaming from a NAS device.

In my [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63334/xbox-360-wont-play-mpeg-4-video-files) on gaming.stackexchange.com, it's come up, that perhaps the constant bit rate audio is the cause of incompatibility.

I am able to convert the MP4 file to an MP4 file using **YouTube Downloader** that *will* play on the XBox. The **YouTube Downloader** generated file has VBR audio.

With the conversion process I think that the video quality is getting degraded. How can I convert just the audio from CBR to VBR?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Avidemux or Yamb to separate audio and video tracks, then convert the CBR to VBR audio and use avidemux to join them together.

I had a slightly different issue ([see my question here](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/3766/674)) but in playing around with the tools recommended, I found this functionality.